# EF linq/lambdas join 2 tables with concat

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, concatenation

I want to join 2 tables (People and Properties), the table properties has multiple rows for one row (name) of the table people, so I want to concat the values of property in table B to have them all in one row for one name of table people.

Example of the tables

People

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 27 |
| Joe | 36 |
| Jim | 16 |

Properties

| Name | Property |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Smart |
| Jane | Funny |
| Jane | Good-looking |
| Joe | Smart |
| Joe | Workaholic |
| Jim | Funny |
| Jim | Young |

Ex of result:

People older than 26

| Name | Properties |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Smart, Funny, Good-looking |
| Joe | Smart, Workaholic |

How can I do it in linq with lambdas, how do I use a string.join for the concat?

Comment: so Jane Smart,Jane Funny,Jane Good-looking are same Jane 27 ?

Comment: Jane   Smart,Funny,Good-looking (concat of the results for jane)

Comment: Specify the exact version of the Entity Framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

as my understanding you are looking how to left join tables to apply a where condition. this is an example how to link'em:

```
void Main()
{
    var Properties = new List<property>();
    Properties.Add(new property("Jane", "Smart"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Jane", "Funny"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Jane", "Good-looking"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Joe" ,"Smart"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Joe" ,"Workaholic"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Jim" ,"Funny"));
    Properties.Add(new property("Jim" ,"Young"));

    var People = new List<Person>();
    People.Add(new Person("Jane",27));
    People.Add(new Person("Joe",36));
    People.Add(new Person("Jim",16));

    //join tables
    People
            .GroupJoin(
                    Properties,
                    ppl => ppl.Name,
                    prop => prop.Name,
                    (ppl, prop) => new { Properties = prop, People = ppl}
                )
                .Select(s => s)
                //.Where(w=> w.People.Age == 27)
                .ToList()
            .Dump();
}

public class property
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Property {get;set;}
    public property(string v1, string v2){
        Name = v1;
        Property = v2;
    }
}

public class Person { 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public Person(string n, int a){
        Name = n;
        Age = a;
    }
}
```

**EDITED**:
check this query update:

```
var list = People
            .GroupJoin(
                    Properties,
                    ppl => ppl.Name,
                    prop => prop.Name,
                    (ppl, prop) => new { Properties = prop, People = ppl}
                )
                .Where(w => w.People.Age == 27)
                .Select(s => new { lst = s.Properties.Select(ss => ss.Property)})
                .FirstOrDefault()
            .Dump();
        string result = String.Join(",", list.lst).Dump();
}
```

[image]

result: (if you uncomment where condition you will have filtered)
[image]

tables:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
to populate list (commented where condition):

```
var list = People
            .GroupJoin(
                    Properties,
                    ppl => ppl.Name,
                    prop => prop.Name,
                    (ppl, prop) => new { Properties = prop, People = ppl}
                )
                //.Where(w => w.People.Age == 27)
                .Select(s => new {  s.People.Name,
                                    lst = String.Join(",", s.Properties.Select(ss => ss.Property))})
                .ToList()
                
            .Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i want to string join the all the properties for one persone , like li    
 for exemple 1 ligne      jane  -->  Smart,Funny,Good-looking (concat of the prop for jane)

Comment: is there a way  to have them both (name and list of props ) in the same object in the query (the same new) not in an outside result string  , caus i need to populate a grid with them so i need to loop through one same object (per iteration) wich has the name and the according prop list   , thanks

Comment: .Select(s => new { lst = String.Join(",", s.Properties.Select(ss => ss.Property))})
    .FirstOrDefault().lst
to have a list: .Select(s => new {  s.People.Name,
         lst = String.Join(",", s.Properties.Select(ss => ss.Property))})
    .ToList()